Ubuntu Studio 23.10 Will not mount NTFS formatted memory stick
Ubuntu Studio 23.10 Will not mount&open NTFS formatted memory sticks.
(Ubuntu Studio 22.04 will mount&open my NTFS formatted memory sticks.)
Running 'sudo parted -l' on the 23.10 system shows the memory sticks correctly.
I have checked that 'fuse3' and 'ntfs-3g'are running on the system.
Am i missing something?
Any help appreciated
Graham.

Was the NTFS used with Windows? And either fast startup or hibernation enabled in Windows. That sets hibernation flag & prevents standard mount of NTFS to prevent damage as hibernation will just restore it to what it was. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation
Can you manually mount in read only?

"Can you manually mount in read only?"  When using 23.10 - No, they will not Mount/Open. When using 22.04 Yes, everything works correctly. These NTFS memory sticks are regularly moved and carry files between Windows/Mac and Linux machines.

Force removal of hiberfil from Ubuntu
http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation
Force mount, read only (ro), change example with sda3 to your correct NTFS partition:
sudo mkdir /media/windows &
sudo mount -t ntfs -o ro /dev/sda3 /media/windows  Have you run chkdsk from Windows, works better than ntfsfix from Linux. Although ntfsfix may say what issue is.
